# Lebesgue outer measure of the union is strictly less than the sum of the measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Show that it exists $A , B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A \cap B = \emptyset $ and 
\begin{align*}
\lambda^{*} (A \cup B) < \lambda^{*} (A) + \lambda^{*} (B) 
\end{align*}

I tried to use Carathéodory's criterium and Vitali's theorem  but without success. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you willing to accept the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set $V$?

The very definition of *measurable* states that there must be a set $E$ with
$$\lambda^*(E) < \lambda^*(E \cap V) + \lambda^*(E \setminus V).$$

Let $A = E \cap V$ and $B = E \setminus V$.

Comment: Perfect, it's so clear, thank you!!